# Confusion about reading Surat in Rakat

Tags: salat

Can we read the same surah in all rakats of salat? Eg. If I read "Surah Kosar" in Farz, can I read it again in Sunnah r nawafil or not.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, We are very glad to have you as a member here, we suggest you look at the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  We would also like to recommend that you look around the site to get used to how it works.

Comment: You could even read the same surat in all your prayers in both raka'at where reading a surat beside al-fatiha is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in doing such.  And there is nothing preventing one from doing that.  It is narrated in [Saheeh Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/169) of an Imam who used to recite a surah and another one with it in each Rak'ah.  Furthermore that Fard, Sunan, and Tatawu' salat are different prayers, you may read surat Al Fatihah and any surat you wish in each of them.  Allah A'lam, May Allah guide us all.